# Is there a framework for writing phrase structure rules out there that is opensource?

Tags: ruby, lisp, nlp

I've worked with the Xerox toolchain so far, which is powerful, not opensource, and a bit overkill for my current problem. Are there libraries that allow my to implement a phrase structure grammar? Preferably in ruby or lisp.

Comment: What do you mean by implement? Is that parsing of strings to syntax trees, or manipulation of that trees, or something completely different?

Comment: Strings -> Syntax trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no open-source Lisp phrase structure parser available.

But since a parser is actually a black box, it's not so hard to make your application work with a parser written in any language, especially as they produce S-expressions as output. For example, with something like [pfp](https://github.com/wavii/pfp) you can just pipe your sentences as strings to it, then read and process the resulting trees. Or you can wrap a socket server around it and you'll get a distributed system :)

There's also [cl-langutils](https://github.com/eslick/cl-langutils), that may be helpful in some basic NLP tasks, like tokenization and, maybe, POS tagging. But overall, it's much less mature and feature rich, than the commonly used packages, like Stanford's or OpenNLP.